# Where am I making a mistake in my angular code?

Tags: angular

Here is my Angular code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from './movie';
import { Movies } from './movie.datasource';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { LoggingService } from './logging.service';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MovieService {

  constructor(private loggingService: LoggingService){}

  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    this.loggingService.add('MovieService: Listing movies');
    return of(Movies);
  }

  getMovie(id): Observable<Movie> {
    return of(Movies.find(movie=> movie.id === id));
  }
}
```

I'm facing this error.

```
Error: src/app/movie.service.ts:24:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Movie | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Movie>'.
  Type 'Movie | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.

24     return of(Movies.find(movie=> movie.id === id));
```

Where am I doing wrong? it was working in the course I was watching but it didn't work when I wrote it myself.

Comment: The error tells you _exactly_ where you're making the mistake - what _should_ happen if no movie of that ID is found?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I figured out where the error is. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
of(Movies.find(movie=> movie.id === id))
```

Will sometimes return `undefined` so the real return type of the `getMovie` method is `Observable<Movie | undefined>` but you have the return type set to just `Observable<Movie>`.

Change the return type to `Observable<Movie | undefined>` and it should work

Comment: I figured out where the error is. Thank you.

Comment: NO problem.  Have a look a this https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode. Strict mode is set by default in Angular 14 (I think).